# dijit issue: none of the components getting rendered

Tags: dojo, tiles2, jspx, spring-js

I am using SPring JS 2.3.0.RELEASE (which uses dojo 1.6): I tried adding widgets to my page but it never renders

I am using pages through tiles so here's the layout template shopper.jspx

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags">
<jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8" />
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="true" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/dojo/resources/dojo.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/screen.css" />
<c:url var="rootUrl" value="/resources/"/>
<script type="text/javascript" djconfig="parseOnLoad: true" src="${rootUrl}dojo/dojo.js"><jsp:text></jsp:text> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${rootUrl}spring/Spring.js">
  <jsp:text></jsp:text>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${rootUrl}spring/Spring-Dojo.js">
  <jsp:text></jsp:text>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("dojo.parser"); 
</script>
<title>My Shopping</title>
</head>
<body class="nihilo">
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="submenu" />
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" ignore="true" />
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the home.jspx template which overrides body attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<div id="page" class="roundedCorners" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <c:url var="rootUrl" value="/resources/"/>
  <script>
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");  
        dojo.addOnLoad(function()
            {
            // create a BorderContainer as the top widget in the hierarchy
            var bc = new dijit.layout.BorderContainer({style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;"});

            // create a ContentPane as the left pane in the BorderContainer
            var cp1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
               region: "left",
               style: "height: 100px",
               content: "hello world"
            });
            bc.addChild(cp1);

            // create a TabContainer as the center pane in the BorderContainer,
            // which itself contains two children
            var tc = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({region: "center"});
            var tab1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({title: "tab 1"}),
                tab2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({title: "tab 2"});
            tc.addChild( tab1 );
            tc.addChild( tab2 );
            bc.addChild(tc);

            // put the top level widget into the document, and then call startup()
            dojo.byId("inbox").addChild(bc.domNode);
            bc.startup();
        });
    </script>  
    <div id="inbox" class="panel roundedCorners">
        <div id="inboxContainer" dojo-data-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not see any of these widgets getting rendered when I load the page. Also the browser console shows the error:

```
dojo.byId("inbox").addChild is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

dojo.byId("inbox").addChild(bc.domNode);
```

despite having the  `djconfig="parseOnLoad: true"` configuration in place.

**Update:** hereś the initial declarative syntax I tried but could not get it to work.

`shopper.jspx`:

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags">
<jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML"
    doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8" />
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="true" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css"
    media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/screen.css" />
<!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js"
    data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true">
    <jsp:text></jsp:text>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.parser");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionPane");
</script>
<title>My Shopping</title>
</head>
<body class="nihilo">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="submenu" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" ignore="true" />
</body>
</html>
```

the declarative `home.jspx` I copied from dojo tutorial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<div id="page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <div id="inbox" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="width: auto; height:auto" > 
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">Top pane</div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" data-dojo-props="region:'leading'">
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="pane #1">accordion pane #1</div>
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="pane #2">accordion pane #2</div>
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="pane #3">accordion pane #3</div>
     </div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="tab #1">tab pane #1</div>
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="tab #2">tab pane #2</div>
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="tab #3">tab pane #3</div>
     </div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'trailing'">Trailing pane</div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">Bottom pane</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in `screen.css` I have defined the following:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #EAECEE;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#page {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #999;
}
```

And I get no widgets rendered in when I access the page.

**Fixed:** Was ignoring the fact about how dijit places divs, I removed the styles applyed through "page" div id and fixed the height and width as follows:

```
<div xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="width: auto; height:600px;" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a border container in markup and also trying to create one programmatically.

Try this:

Change

```
<div id="inboxContainer" dojo-data-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer">
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="inboxContainer" style="width:800px; height: 600px"></div>
```

create the border container

```
var bc = new dijit.layout.BorderContainer({}, dojo.byId("inboxContainer"));
...
// dojo.byId("inbox").addChild(bc.domNode); // remove this
```

This line of code fails because dojo.byId returns a domNode and a domNode does not have an addChild method.

I also changed the width and height.  Using height: 100% requires all the dom nodes above it in the hierarchy (html, body, roundedCorners, inbox) to also have height: 100% and I couldn't verify in the code posted that this was the case, so eliminate this potential problem for now by specifying a direct height. Once, its working, you can change it back.

Comment: Thanks Craig... I was basically trying my hand at digit to see if it suites well for laying out widgets declaratively. However, there is a larger question. I tried doing through scripts because I cannot get the declarative way to work, it appears more convinient using declarative options so can you also help as to why is it not working for my pages? I have modified the question to include the original descriptive syntax.

Comment: Got it to work! Problem was me ignoring dijit documentation and what you mentioned about styling the height and width. Sometimes I tend to learn the hard way ;-).